# Artifactory startup scripts don't work properly on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: artifactory

Running Artifactory 6.3.3.

Trying to start the service produces the following error in systemd:

```
artifactory.service: New main PID 1359 does not belong to service, and PID file is not owned by root. Refusing.
```

After which it just goes into a continuous restart loop.

This seems to be consistent with the following systemd issue:

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8085

Comment: happened to me too, using 6.3.0 , try many workarounds dont work. had to upgrade to 6.17.4 where this problem would be solved. you can download it here, https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/artifactory-rpms/jfrog-artifactory-oss/